# Partial syntax highlighting in a question

Tags: bug, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

On questions where the code overflows, the syntax highlighting stops wherever the end of the content visible without scrolling is.

[image]

Scrolling down a bit fixes the issue. This problem occurs in Safari on macOS 12.2. I don't have any extensions that could be causing the problem.

After scrolling down:
[image]

Comment: There is only about [5-7](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) years left.